# Angular/RXJS Does a Clickable subscription like async pipe exist

Tags: angular, rxjs, closures

It's common that I have a click event that then triggers a function which uses observable data to process. I have created a closure that acts like the Async Pipe to take 1 and subscribe (not exactly but effectively for this use-case), but I would prefer to use an rxjs native version if it exists. Does it exist?

```
function async(subject, innerSubscribe?: (pipedData) => void) {
  return () => subject.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(innerSubscribe);
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    <button (click)="click()">click</button>
  `,
})
export class App {
  click = async(
    new BehaviorSubject('source data').pipe(
      tap((data) => console.log(data))
    ),
    (data) => console.log(data + ' in subscribe')
  );
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dovlzc?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: I understand what you code does, thanks to the stackblitz,but I cannot comprehend what you are actually trying to achieve. So upon a user clicking the button, an Observable is emitted? And you need to subscribe to it?

Comment: Often when a click event occurs you want do something that requires data that exists in a reactive stream. So a common thing to do is have a method that subscribes to a reactive source and you do stuff in that method. I want to simplify this so you can use a source just like you would to display data in a template using the async pipe. The source data can be anything, for example a selector.

Comment: Is your answer a "yes" to my previous answer? Also, have you considered creating a custom pipe? You could create pipes like the "async" pipe but with your logic

Comment: Upon clicking the button a subscription is made. As far is I know, you can’t pipe a click event but this is basically what I want to try and do.